# Try to check two objects if there equal with if clause

Tags: javascript

I want to check if two objects of my array are equal.

I try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(Object.is(data[i].Attribute_Name, data[i-1].Attribute_Name) && i > 1)
        console.log(data[i].Attribute_Name);
}
```

But I get this errormessage:

> TypeError: data[(i - 1)] is undefined
>
> if(Object.is(data[i].Attribute_Name, data[i-1].Attribute_Name) && i >
>   1)

my objects look like this:

```
Attribute_Name="Einkommen"

Attribute_Name="Einkommen"

Attribute_Name="Einkommen"

Attribute_Name="Ausgaben"

Attribute_Name="Ausgaben"

Attribute_Name="Ausgaben"

Attribute_Name="Alter"

Attribute_Name="Alter"
```

My output of my page are the same.

[image]

The red marked area should not be apear.

Comment: The first time through the loop, `i` is `0`, so `i-1` is `-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time your loop runs, `i == 0`. You are trying to index into the array using `i-1` which is `-1` which is an invalid array index.